# awk append new line to end of line before with matching patterns

Tags: bash, scripting, sed, awk, grep

I have a file that contains the following:

```
TTITLE0=Dispenser (Unreleased, 1995)
TTITLE1=Pivotal (From The Icebreaker 7", 1998)
TTITLE2=Sucker & Dry (From the Sucker & Dry 7", 1997)
TTITLE3=Icebreakers (From The Icebreaker 7", 1998)
TTITLE4=And The Bit Just Chokes Them (From the Sucker & Dry 7", 1997)
TTITLE5=There's A Coldest Day In Every Year (From The Disruption 7", 1
TTITLE5=996)
TTITLE6=A Disruption In The Normal Swing Of Things (From The Disruptio
TTITLE6=n 7", 1996)
TTITLE7=Nostalgia (From the Makoto Split 7" Series w/Small Brown Bike,
TTITLE7= 2001)
TTITLE8=The Knowledgeable Hasbeens (From The Disruption 7", 1996)
TTITLE9=Polar (From The Icebreaker 7", 1998)
TTITLE10=A Disruption In Our Lines Of Influence (From The Disruption 7
TTITLE10=", 1996)
TTITLE11=I Thought There'd Be More Than This (Unreleased, 1996)
```

As you can see, when the title of the track is too long, the title is appended on the next line, with `TTITLE(samenumber)=` in front. What i need to do is make these long titles one line.

My plan of attack was to identify the matching beginning of the lines, add a backslash to the end of the first of the two, use

```sh
cut -d"=" -f 2
```

to remove the

```
TTITLE(num)=
```

then append the second line to the first using the famous `awk` one-liner

```sh
awk '/\\$/ { sub(/\\$/,""); getline t; print $0 t; next }; 1'
```

Testing it out, if I manually add the backslashes and remove the `TTITLE` with `cut`, the `awk` statement works perfectly. On the other hand, if someone has a better idea, please share!

I would prefer using `awk` or `sed` because of the inability to install `perl` or `ruby` on the machines this will be running on, however, if this is the only solution, I can make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
awk -F"=" 'BEGIN {prev_title=""} {if ($1 == prev_title || NR ==1) { printf "%s", $2 } else { prev_title = $1; printf "\n%s", $2}} END {printf "\n"}'
```

This awk will generate the output your are looking for

```
Dispenser (Unreleased, 1995)
Pivotal (From The Icebreaker 7", 1998)
Sucker & Dry (From the Sucker & Dry 7", 1997)
Icebreakers (From The Icebreaker 7", 1998)
And The Bit Just Chokes Them (From the Sucker & Dry 7", 1997)
There's A Coldest Day In Every Year (From The Disruption 7", 1996)
A Disruption In The Normal Swing Of Things (From The Disruption 7", 1996)
Nostalgia (From the Makoto Split 7" Series w/Small Brown Bike, 2001)
The Knowledgeable Hasbeens (From The Disruption 7", 1996)
Polar (From The Icebreaker 7", 1998)
A Disruption In Our Lines Of Influence (From The Disruption 7", 1996)
I Thought There'd Be More Than This (Unreleased, 1996)
```

In case you need to keep TITLE:

```sh
awk -F"=" 'BEGIN {prev_title=""} {if ($1 == prev_title) { printf "%s", $2 } else { prev_title = $1; if (NR==1) {printf "%s", $0} else {printf "\n%s", $0}}} END {printf "\n"}'
```

and it yeids

```
TTITLE0=Dispenser (Unreleased, 1995)
TTITLE1=Pivotal (From The Icebreaker 7", 1998)
TTITLE2=Sucker & Dry (From the Sucker & Dry 7", 1997)
TTITLE3=Icebreakers (From The Icebreaker 7", 1998)
TTITLE4=And The Bit Just Chokes Them (From the Sucker & Dry 7", 1997)
TTITLE5=There's A Coldest Day In Every Year (From The Disruption 7", 1996)
TTITLE6=A Disruption In The Normal Swing Of Things (From The Disruption 7", 1996)
TTITLE7=Nostalgia (From the Makoto Split 7" Series w/Small Brown Bike, 2001)
TTITLE8=The Knowledgeable Hasbeens (From The Disruption 7", 1996)
TTITLE9=Polar (From The Icebreaker 7", 1998)
TTITLE10=A Disruption In Our Lines Of Influence (From The Disruption 7", 1996)
TTITLE11=I Thought There'd Be More Than This (Unreleased, 1996)
```

Comment: this was exactly what i needed, and +1 for going above and beyond with the second example.

Comment: I thing the `BEGIN` part is not needed since in `awk` an uninitialized variable will be resolved to `""` anyhow: `awk -F"=" '$1==prev_title{printf "%s",$2;next}{prev_title=$1}NR==1{printf "%s",$0;next}{printf "\n%s",$0}END{print ""}'`
`

Answer (score 1):

I believe all this can be done in awk itself. Try this awk script:

```
awk -F '=' '{if (p==""){p=$1;line=$2} else if(p!=$1){print p "=" line; p=$1; line=$2} else if (p==$1) {line=line "\\\n" $2} } END{print p "=" line}' file
```

For the above input file it gives:

```
TTITLE0=Dispenser (Unreleased, 1995)
TTITLE1=Pivotal (From The Icebreaker 7", 1998)
TTITLE2=Sucker & Dry (From the Sucker & Dry 7", 1997)
TTITLE3=Icebreakers (From The Icebreaker 7", 1998)
TTITLE4=And The Bit Just Chokes Them (From the Sucker & Dry 7", 1997)
TTITLE5=There's A Coldest Day In Every Year (From The Disruption 7", 1\
996)
TTITLE6=A Disruption In The Normal Swing Of Things (From The Disruptio\
n 7", 1996)
TTITLE7=Nostalgia (From the Makoto Split 7" Series w/Small Brown Bike,\
 2001)
TTITLE8=The Knowledgeable Hasbeens (From The Disruption 7", 1996)
TTITLE9=Polar (From The Icebreaker 7", 1998)
TTITLE10=A Disruption In Our Lines Of Influence (From The Disruption 7\
", 1996)
TTITLE11=I Thought There'd Be More Than This (Unreleased, 1996)
```

Comment: thanks! this got me half way there, and then i was able to use the other awk from my question to get me there. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
awk -F= '
  {title[$1] = title[$1] $2}
  END {for (id in title) print id "=" title[id]}
' titles.txt | sort -V
```